# Prime gap around x expressed as $w(x)\log^{w(x)}x$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

For  $ x $ a positive real number greater than  $3 $ and not equal to a prime, there exists a unique pair of consecutive primes  $ (p,q) $ such that  $ p<x<q $. Let  $ g(x) : =q-p $. Expressing  $ g(x) $ as  $ w(x)\log^{w(x)}x $ with  $ w(x) $ positive, what is the best upper bound for  $ w(x) $ one can get in term of  $ x $?

---

Comment: This is just a change of variables from the best known results we have on prime gaps, namely Baker/Harman/Pintz's result that $q-p \ll x^{0.525}$. This means that $w(x)$ is a bit smaller than $0.525 \log x / \log\log x$.

Comment: Thank you. Is it known whether the sequence of general term  $ u_n : =\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}w(p_{n}+h) $ is stricty decreasing ?

Comment: Please use more standard notation for your questions. It seems that your $u_n$ is just a change-of-variable version of $p_{n+1}-p_n$, which is nowhere near monotonic.